# mysql analyze table results in odd behavior

Tags: mysql

I noticed that the table totals I get when running:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database';
```

were resulting in incorrect totals. I also read that doing:

```
analyze table 'my_table';
```

would update the information correctly. But it appears that's not the case. So, to set the baseline:

```
  mysql> select count(*) from my_table;
  +----------+
  | count(*) |
  +----------+
  |    61782 |
  +----------+
  1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Next, what the stats show:

```
  mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
  +--------------------+------------+
  | TABLE_NAME         | TABLE_ROWS |
  +--------------------+------------+
  | my_table           |      58378 |
  +--------------------+------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

clearly, that's not right, so I perform the analyze and check again:

```
  mysql> analyze table my_table;
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | Table                        | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | my_database.my_table         | analyze | status   | OK       |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  1 row in set (0.02 sec)

  mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
  +--------------------+------------+
  | TABLE_NAME         | TABLE_ROWS |
  +--------------------+------------+
  | my_table           |      56439 |
  +--------------------+------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ok, it changed, but it's still wrong. So I did it several more times:

```
  mysql> analyze table my_table;
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | Table                        | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | my_database.my_table         | analyze | status   | OK       |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  1 row in set (0.02 sec)

  mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
  +--------------------+------------+
  | TABLE_NAME         | TABLE_ROWS |
  +--------------------+------------+
  | my_table           |      58766 |
  +--------------------+------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql> analyze table my_table;
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | Table                        | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | my_database.my_table         | analyze | status   | OK       |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  1 row in set (0.02 sec)

  mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
  +--------------------+------------+
  | TABLE_NAME         | TABLE_ROWS |
  +--------------------+------------+
  | my_table           |      65749 |
  +--------------------+------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql> analyze table my_table;
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | Table                        | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  | my_database.my_table         | analyze | status   | OK       |
  +------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
  1 row in set (0.02 sec)

  mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
  +--------------------+------------+
  | TABLE_NAME         | TABLE_ROWS |
  +--------------------+------------+
  | my_table           |      61870 |
  +--------------------+------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and, as you can see, I never got the same number and none of them are the actual row count. My question is this: is this an indicator that I've got a problem with my database (it's doing it on all tables) or is this just a bug in MySQL?

Details of my environment:

Server version: 5.6.43 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
All tables are INNODB, character set is utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For InnoDB, the `table_rows` statistic is an *estimate*, not an exact count. The value isn't guaranteed to be the exact row count.

No, this isn't a bug in MySQL. The InnoDB statistics are not wrong. Behavior is documented in MySQL Reference Manual.

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-statistics.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html